# Modifying multiple dataframes at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I am working with: df and df1. They contain exactly the same columns. I was trying to remove the same column from both using a loop (to avoid copying/pasting my code). I tried two options. One worked and one didn't so I was wondering why....

**Option 1 (Worked):**

```
x = [df, df1]

for i in x:
  i.drop(['val'], axis = 1, inplace=True )
```

**Option 2 (Failed):**

```
x = [df, df1]

for i in x:
  i = i[['date', 'time', 'a', 'b']].copy() #keeping all the variables except the one I want to drop.
```

P.S. by "failed" I mean that I was able to run the code but my dataframes were not modified.

Comment: You don't need `copy` here, the dataframe is the same after `copy`

Comment: You need `copy` or risk a [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) down the line. By then, it may not be obvious which line of code caused the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is pointer references.

```py
# You are modifying df and df1 directly
# i is simply a pointer to the objects at the same addresses
for i in [df, df1]:
    i.drop(['val'], axis = 1, inplace=True )
  
for i in [df, df1]:
    # You create a new object and point i to it.
    # However, this object is immediately discarded because i is assigned to
    # the next item in the iteration list. df and df1 were never modified
    i = i[['date', 'time', 'a', 'b']].copy()
```